# Anyone know why it scrapes only 1 page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape multiple pages, but my current code only manages to scrape 1 page. How can I fix this to scrape multiple pages?

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

pages = list(range(1, 20))
for page in pages:
    req = requests.get("https://katmoviehd.sk/page/{}".format(page))
    
    soup=BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")
    soup
    page1 = soup.find_all('h2')[1:]
        
    Category = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'meta-category')
    Category
        
    Category_list = []
        
    for i in Category:
        Category2 = i.text
        Category_list.append(Category2)
        
    link_list = []
        
    for i in page1:
        link = (i.find("a")['href'])
        link_list.append(link)       
    title_list = []    
    for i in page1:
        title = (i.find("a")['title'])
        title_list.append(title)
            
            
    Table = pd.DataFrame({'Links':link_list, 'Title':title_list, 'Category':Category_list})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to check the value of `Table` each time through the loop? Does that give you a hint as to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working output with pagination:

```
    import requests 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    page = 1
    title_list = []
    link_list = []
    Category_list = []
    for page in range(0, 10):
        url = f"https://katmoviehd.sk/page/{page}".format(page=page)
        response = requests.get(url)
        html = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        page1 = soup.find_all('h2')[1:]
            
        Category = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'meta-category')
        Category
                          
        for i in Category:
            Category2 = i.text
            Category_list.append(Category2)
                  
        for i in page1:
            link = (i.find("a")['href'])
            link_list.append(link)       
              
        for i in page1:
            title = (i.find("a")['title'])
            title_list.append(title)
                    
                    
   Table = pd.DataFrame({'Links':link_list, 'Title':title_list, 'Category':Category_list})
   print(Table)
```

OUTPUT:
Each page contains 16 items and I'm going to scrape only 10 pages and total output 160. You can increase or decrease range of page numbers whatever you wish.

```
Links  ...
           Category
0           https://katmoviehd.sk/stillwater-s01-2020/  ...  Animated / APPLE TV+ / Dual Audio / Family / T...
1            https://katmoviehd.sk/what-if-2021-hindi/  ...  Action / Adventure / Animated 
/ Disney + / Dua...
2           https://katmoviehd.sk/dcs-titans-season-3/  ...  Action / Adventure / Fantasy / In English (Onl...
3              https://katmoviehd.sk/the-passing-2011/  ...                 Dual Audio / Dubbed Movie / Horror
4    https://katmoviehd.sk/annette-2021-bengali-dub...  ...                        Bengali 
Dubbed (Unofficial)
..                                                 ...  ...
                ...
155          https://katmoviehd.sk/rick-and-morty-s05/  ...  Adventure / Animated / Comedy 
/ sci-fi / TV shows
156                   https://katmoviehd.sk/backtrace/  ...  Action / crime / Drama / Dual 
Audio / Dubbed M...
157       https://katmoviehd.sk/rattle-can-full-movie/  ...                Hindi Subtitles 
/ In English (Only)
158               https://katmoviehd.sk/streetdance-2/  ...  Drama / Dual Audio / Dubbed Movie / Music / ro...
159  https://katmoviehd.sk/midnight-in-the-switchgr...  ...
  Unofficial Dubbed

[160 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all movies into a dataframe, you can use next example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_data = []
for page in range(1, 5):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    req = requests.get("https://katmoviehd.sk/page/{}".format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

    for item in soup.select("li.post"):
        all_data.append(
            {
                "Title": item.h2.get_text(strip=True),
                "Categories": ", ".join(
                    a.get_text(strip=True)
                    for a in item.select(".meta-category a")
                ),
                "Link": item.h2.a["href"],
            }
        )

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                                                          Title                                                                                          Categories                                                          Link
0            Stillwater (Season 1) Hindi (5.1 DD) [Dual Audio] All Episodes | WEB-DL 1080p 720p 480p HD [2020 Apple TV+ Series]                                        Animated, APPLE TV+, Dual Audio, Family, TV SERIES [Dubbed ]                    https://katmoviehd.sk/stillwater-s01-2020/
1                           What If…? (Season 1) Hindi Dubbed [HQ Fan Dub] WEB-DL 1080p 720p 480p [Episode 3 Added !] TV Series               Action, Adventure, Animated, Disney +, Dual Audio, HQ Fan Dubbed, TV SERIES [Dubbed ]                     https://katmoviehd.sk/what-if-2021-hindi/
2                            The Passing (2011) UNRATED WEBRip 720p & 480p [Dual Audio] [Hindi Dubbed (ORG) – English] Eng Subs                                                                    Dual Audio, Dubbed Movie, Horror                       https://katmoviehd.sk/the-passing-2011/
3                                         Vacation Friends (2021) Web-DL 480p 720p 1080p [In English 5.1 DD] ESubs (Full Movie)                                                 Adventure, Comedy, Hollywood Eng, In English (Only)               https://katmoviehd.sk/vacation-friends-2021-hd/
4                        D.P. (Season 1) [Hindi Dubbed 5.1 DD + Korean] Dual Audio | WEB-DL 1080p 720p 480p [NF K-Drama Series]                   Dual Audio, Korean, Korean Drama (In Hindi), NetFlix, Series, TV SERIES [Dubbed ]                               https://katmoviehd.sk/d-p-2021/
5                  SAS: Rise of the Black Swan (2021) Hindi Dubbed (5.1 DD) [Dual Audio] WEB-DL 1080p 720p 480p HD [Full Movie]                                          Action, Dual Audio, Dubbed Movie, Movie, NetFlix, Thriller                         https://katmoviehd.sk/sas-red-notice/
6                             He’s All That (2021) Hindi Dubbed (5.1 DD) [Dual Audio] WEBRip 1080p 720p 480p HD [Netflix Movie]                                     Comedy, Dual Audio, Dubbed Movie, Movie, NetFlix, romance, TEEN                           https://katmoviehd.sk/hes-all-that/
7                                      The Virtuoso (2021) Hindi (Voice Over) Dubbed + English [Dual Audio] BluRay 720p [1XBET]                                                                                   Unofficial Dubbed                       https://katmoviehd.sk/virtuoso-2021-vo/
8                                  Cruella (2021) Hindi Dubbed (ORG 5.1 DD) [Dual Audio] Web-DL 1080p 720p 480p HD [Full Movie]                                                   Comedy, crime, Disney +, Dual Audio, Dubbed Movie                                https://katmoviehd.sk/cruella/
9                              The Vault (2021) Hindi Dubbed (ORG) [Dual Audio] BluRay 1080p 720p 480p HD [Way Down Full Movie]                                               Action, Adventure, Dual Audio, Dubbed Movie, Thriller                          https://katmoviehd.sk/way-down-2021/


...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: You will get only one page because you're rewriting your variable `Table` every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
page = 1
title_list = []
link_list = []
Category_list = []
while page != 550:
    url = f"https://katmoviehd.sk/page/{page}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    page1 = soup.find_all('h2')[1:]
        
    Category = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'meta-category')
    Category
                      
    for i in Category:
        Category2 = i.text
        Category_list.append(Category2)
              
    for i in page1:
        link = (i.find("a")['href'])
        link_list.append(link)       
          
    for i in page1:
        title = (i.find("a")['title'])
        title_list.append(title)
                
                
    Table = pd.DataFrame({'Links':link_list, 'Title':title_list, 'Category':Category_list})
    page = page + 1
```